# PNG options to produce smaller file size when using savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to produce a plot which I then save to a PNG file using matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.

It all works fine, but the filesize is quite large (about 120Kb).

I can use ImageMagik afterwards (via the shell) to reduce the filesize to 38Kb without any loss of quality by reducing the number of colors and turning off dither:

```
convert +dither -colors 256 orig.png new.png
```

My question is: can I do this within matplotlib? I have searched the documentation and can't find any thing pertaining to setting the number of colors used when saving, etc....

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a `dpi=` kwarg to savefig() which might help you reduce the filesize (depending on what you want to do with your graphs afterwards). Failing that, I think that the Python Imaging Library ( http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ ) will almost certainly do what you want.

Comment: Cheers, will have a look at PIL. Don't really want to change the dpi if I can help it...

Answer (score 13):

This is what I do to run matplotlib image through PIL (now Pillow)

```
import cStringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
```

...

```
ram = cStringIO.StringIO()
plt.savefig(ram, format='png')
ram.seek(0)
im = Image.open(ram)
im2 = im.convert('RGB').convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE)
im2.save( filename , format='PNG')
```

Comment: This was really helpful! For Python 3, I used io.BytesIO instead of cStringIO.StringIO. See [StringIO in python3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914472/stringio-in-python3)